# unable to access to the state's array after fetching

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to access the workerId (which is in the json file, to use it for second fetch in the app so that it shows worker information). The fetch works and shows the data but when I console.log(this.state.ordersData.workerId), I get an error that it's undefined. How can I get to workerId and store it in a variable?

A portion of my json is below:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "deadline": 1563046159,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            "id": "83f007d6",
            "name": "Work order 83f007d6",
            "workerId": 1
        },
        {
            "deadline": 1562752687,
            "description": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
            "id": "cb23c526",
            "name": "Work order cb23c526",
            "workerId": 1
        },
]
}
```

A portion of App.js below :

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Order from './components/Order';
    import Form from './components/Form'
    import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state={
    ordersData: []
  }
} 

  componentDidMount() {

    fetch("https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/work_orders")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({
          ordersData: data.orders
          });
          console.log(this.state.ordersData.workerId)
        })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
      }); 
  }
```

in the console it shows undefined

EDIT 1

```
fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${workerId}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            workersData: data,
          });

        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        });
```

EDIT 2

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Worker from './Worker'

import Moment from 'react-moment';
import '../App.css'


class Order extends Component {

state={
        workersData :{worker:[]} ,

    }


componentDidMount() {
    let workerId = this.props.workerId;
    fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${workerId}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            workersData: data,
          });

        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        });
    }



    render(){
        let workerId = this.props.workerId;
        console.log(workerId);

        return(

            <div className ='order-card'>
                <div >
                    <p>{this.props.orderName}</p>
                    <p>{this.props.description}</p>
                </div>
                <Worker name = {this.state.workersData.worker.name}
                        email = {this.state.workersData.worker.email}
                        companyName = {this.state.workersData.worker.companyName}
                        image = {this.state.workersData.worker.image}/>
                <div className="order-card-time"><span className = 'bold'>Deadline :</span><Moment format="YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm">{this.props.deadline}</Moment></div> 
            </div>
        )
    }

}
export default Order;
```

Comment: Where you are writing second fetch? After first fetch immediately?

Comment: actually I passed the workerId to the child component and did the second fetch there and it's working. but I want to do both fetches in the App.js

Comment: look at my edite

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is `async`, so `console.log` will show undefined only because state is not set yet, you can use `callback` in `setState`,

```
this.setState({
   ordersData: data.orders
},() => console.log(this.state.ordersData[0].workerId));
```

**Update**

You can make you of `componentDidUpdate`, because at the time child's `componentDidMount` executes your `parent's` `setState` is not executed due to `async` nature.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
   if(prevProps.workerId !== this.props.workerId){
    let workerId = this.props.workerId;
    fetch(`https://www.hatchways.io/api/assessment/workers/${workerId}`)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          this.setState({
            workersData: data,
          });

        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err)
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write second fetch based on `workerId` in setState callback.